# Can not type input box in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a simple React application, if I type input can not type automatically disable the input box every time click to type after disabled again click to type after disabled. could you please provide your Advice? below my code.

```
const TimeInputRow = ({ data, onFieldChange, onAddRow }) => {

    console.log(data)
    const {existing_date,  time_start, time_end, percent_to_count, days_addtion } = data;
    
    console.log(existing_date)
    // const formattedDate = new Date(existing_date).toLocaleDateString('en-GB');

    return (
      <div className='d-f time-adding'>
        {/* Use formattedDate instead of date */}
        <input type="text" value={existing_date || ""} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('existing_date', e.target.value)} />

        <input type="text" pattern="[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" value={time_start} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('time_start', e.target.value)} />
        <input type="text" pattern="[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" value={time_end} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('time_end', e.target.value)} />
        <input type="number" placeholder="Percent Count" value={percent_to_count} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('percent_to_count', parseInt(e.target.value))} />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Days Addtion" value={days_addtion} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('days_addtion', e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={onAddRow} className='add-row'><FaRegPlusSquare /></button>

      </div>
    
    
    );
  };
```

`handle change code:`

```
 const handleFieldChange = (index, field, value) => {
     
    const newRows = [...rows];
    newRows[index][field] = value;
    setRows(newRows);
  
  };


  {rows.map((data, index) => (
            <div key={index} className='d-f'>
               <TimeInputRow
          key={index}
          data={data}
          onFieldChange={(field, value) => handleFieldChange(index, field, value)}
          onAddRow={handleAddRow}
        />
              <button className='remove-row' onClick={() => handleRemoveRow(index)}><FaRegTrashAlt /></button>
            </div>
          ))}
          <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={handleSubmit}>Save</button>
```

Comment: You can't use regular JavaScript variables in React like this - you need to use hooks and useState for variables that are render-aware. Read about useState.

Comment: Please study about [React hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)